# on boost::iter_split documentation

Tags: c++, string, boost

I came across the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/iter_split.html) for `boost::iter_split`. Part of the description says

> Iteration is done using built-in find_iterator, so the real searching is performed only when needed.

What does it really mean? The result has to be a container of containers, so isn't it true that searching will always be done even if the user only wants the first split?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're right. Of course, with a concrete container to receive the token iterator ranges, all the finding happens *before returning with all those ranges appended to the result container*.

So all the finding indeed will have been done.

(Stretching the imagination a bit: *Perhaps the documentation is hinting at the input side of things: if you supply input iterators, information might not be immediately available, and obviously the algorithm will not return until the end iterator has been encountered.*)

<sub>That is unless adding a token to the result range/reading from the source iterator aborts the search with an exception</sub>

---

I presume that the comment is a left-over from copying from corresponding find functions that take an output iterator. The output iterator might actually stop the algorithm halfway (consider a `function_output_iterator` with a lambda that throws when more than *`n`* elements have been found).

You could send a pull request to the library devs, or perhaps raise it on the boost mailing lists.

Comment: What sort of input iterators are you suggesting? I can think of `boost::iterator_range`, but not sure what the template arguments should be.

Comment: I meant [InputIterator](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/InputIterator.html) (like `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` e.g.). It's hardly relevant though, that was just trying to think of ways in which the documented claim might still be half-sensible :0